# Terminal Coloring using ZSH

Tags: linux, zsh, colors

I have seen several other users terminals that are **very** colorful, even the terminal for Parrot OS is extra colorful now. I am using **zsh** on ***Kali***, just FYI, this there a way to create your own color scheme for a terminal's output or the `prompt`? I know that you are able to change the color schemes that are already builtin, but is there a way to create your own scheme?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to use my [ZColors plugin](https://github.com/marlonrichert/zcolors) plus the [`zsh-syntax-highlighting` plugin](https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh-syntax-highlighting) and then add a [prompt theme](https://github.com/search?q=zsh+prompt+theme&type=) of your choice.

Comment: Thanks, I will give it a try.